# will create method work on morphable model?

Tags: laravel

```
$comment = Comment::create(['title' => 'test']);
```

will this work with model that is morphable?

It  has these columns:

```
        $table->string('commentable_type');
        $table->biginteger('commentable_id')->unsigned()->index();
```

it doesn't seem that they will be filled if I use create here or will they?

right now I am doing it like this:

```
        $comment = new Comment();
        $comment->title = $title;
        $comment->body = $body;
        $this->comments()->save($comment);
```

but would like to swtich to create so I can mass assign instead of one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$this->comments()->create($array);
```

Is definitely available for morphable models.

From Taylor Otwell himself: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/322

Comment: sorry a follow up question. create($request->all) gives create() must be of the type array, null given and create($request) gives create() must be of the type array, object given... How do I pass in $request correctly?

Comment: `all()` is a function. That's why it said `null given`. Do `create($request->all())`. Simply add parenthesis.